and I counted it again
Tom counted the money, and I counted it again.
I think that would normally mean he counted it once and I counted it once. I suppose it could be used if I had counted it before. Would you agree with that?
-"Tom has already counted the money."
-"I don't care if he has or he hasn't. I don't trust Tom. Count it again!"
In this case again, I'd say that most likely the addressee has not counted the money before, although that might have been the case. Would you agree with that?
Many thanks

Context is needed. Perhaps I counted it and Tom then got a different result, so I counted it again. But in some contexts you would be right.

Yes; you're right in both cases, and you're also right in each case that one of the meanings is more usual but the other meaning is also possible.
